# .Why this jQuery accordion code don't work in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

Why my following code don't work in IE7 but work in chrome, opera, mozila....

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    $(".sub").hide();
    $("tr#sub1").show();
    $(".expandSub a").click(function(){
        var relValue = $(this).attr("rel");
        $("tr#"+relValue).toggle();
        var t = $(this).text();
        if(t=="+")$(this).html("-");
        else if(t=="-")$(this).html("+");
        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tr class="headRow">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="350px" align="center">Title</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="leadRow">
        <td class="expandSub"><a href="" rel="sub1">-</a></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Cake</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub" id="sub1">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Red Velvet Cakes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub evenRow" id="sub1">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Cupcake Recipes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub" id="sub1">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Pineapple Mojo Cake</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub evenRow" id="sub1">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Carrot Cake Recipes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub" id="sub1">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Zucchini Chocolate Chip Cake</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="leadRow">
        <td class="expandSub"><a href="" rel="sub2">+</a></td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Cookies</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub" id="sub2">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Chocolate Chip Cookie Recipes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub evenRow" id="sub2">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Sugar Cookie Recipes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub" id="sub2">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Filled Cookies</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub evenRow" id="sub2">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Sugared Black Raspberry Tea Cookiess</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="leadRow" rel="sub3">
        <td class="expandSub"><a href="" rel="sub3">+</a></td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Appetizers</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub" id="sub3">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Hummus Recipes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub evenRow" id="sub3">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Cheese Balls</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, I'd say it's because your HTML is invalid.  In HTML, your ID must be absolutely unique.

You repeat your IDs (i.e. `id="sub1"`) and this is invalid.  Likely IE7 is none too happy about that.  I'm surprised any browser works, to be honest.

Paste your HTML into the W3C's validation service to see all the errors:

http://validator.w3.org/